# How to properly use "iterate" and "partial" in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, square-root

Most reference to `iterate` are for operators, and all the applications on functions are so confusing that I still don't get how to use `iterate` in my code, and what `partial` is.

I am doing a programming homework, trying to use Newton's method to get square root for a number n. That is, with guess as the initial approximation, keep computing new approximations by computing the average of the approximation and n/approximation. Continue until the difference between the two most recent approximations is less than epsilon.

I am trying to do the approximation part first, I believe that is something I need to use iterate and partial. And later the epsilon is something I need to use "take"?

Here is the code I have for approximation without the epsilon:

```
(defn sqrt [n guess]
  (iterate (partial sqrt n) (/ (+ n (/ n guess)) 2)))
```

This code does not work properly though, when I enter `(sqrt 2 2)`, it gives me `(3/2 user=> ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.divide (Numbers.java:155)`.

I guess this is the part I need to iterate over and over again? Could someone please give me some hints? Again, this is a homework problem, so please do not provide me direct solution to the entire problem, I need some ideas and explanations that I can learn from.

Comment: What is an `operator`? I don't think there is anything called an operator in clojure. Things like `+` or `-` or `*` or `/` that would be an operator in another language, are just functions in clojure. You can use any other function where you would use them (as long as it takes the same arguments).

Comment: Hi guys, thank you so much for all your help! I got everything figured out. Since it is a homework not due yet, I don't think I can post my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`partial` takes a function and at least one parameter for that function and returns a new function that expects the rest of the parameters.

```
(def take-five (partial take 5))
(take-five [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10])
;=> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

`iterate` generates an infinite sequence by taking two parameters: a function and a seed value. The seed value is used as the first element in the generated list and the second is computed by applying the function to the seed, the second value is used as the input for the function to get the third value and so on.

```
(take-five (iterate inc 0))
;=> (0 1 2 3 4)
```

ClojureDocs offers good documentation on both functions: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate and http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partial.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I have figured this one out!

Answer (score 4):

So, @ponzao explained quite well what `iterate` and `partial` do, and @yonki made the point that you don't really need it. If you like to explore some more seq functions it's probably a good idea to try it anyways (although the overhead from lazy sequences might result in a  somewhat not ideal performance).

Hints:

- `(iterate #(sqrt n %) initial-approximation)` will give you a seq of approximations.
- you can use `partition` to create pairs of subsequent approximations.
- discard everything not fulfilling the epsilon condition using `drop-while`
- get result.

It's probably quite rewarding to solve this using sequences since you get in contact with a lot of useful seq functions.

**Note:** There is a full solution somewhere in the edit history of this answer. Sorry for that, didn't fully get the "homework" part.

Comment: Thank you for that! I got my answer figured out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point. You don't need `iterate` neither `partial` too.

If you need to execute some computation till condition is fulfilled you can use easy to understand `loop/recur` instruction. `loop/recur` can be understood as: do some computation, check if condition is fulfilled, if yes return computed value, if not repeat computation.

Since you don't want entire solution, only an advice where to go, have a proper look on `loop/recur` and everything gonna be all right.

@noisesmith made good point. `reduce` is not for computing till condition is fullfiled, but may be useful when performing some computation with limited number of steps.

Comment: loop / recur is helpful if you are not used to functional programming, because it is closer to an imperative way of doing things, but it is not usually the best way to solve a problem. Also, reduce is not for doing something until a condition is fulfilled, it is for folding across a collection (with the special case that you can jump out imperatively with `reduced`).

Comment: I know loop/recur is not the best way to go, when you're into functional programming. But, as you said, it's close to imperative loops and may be useful when someones knowledge about functional isn't great.


And yeah, I know what is reduce for. Still, it may be useful to perform some computation with limited number of steps.

The question was not about idiomatic, functional Clojure, but about possibility to resolve actual problem. I choose loop/recur casue it's easy to understand.

Comment: I think this is bad advice. Iterate and Partial are very useful tools to know, and more idiomatic than loop/recur, and the OP's question is an excellent use-case for iterate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally get why you are convincing me to use loop/recur. And I agree that they are good ideas. But I think the point of this home work is to help me get a better understanding of iterate/partial. But thank you again for helping!